# -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to parse through an API for my iOS app. However, for some reason the API returns JSON that I can't seem to parse (using NSJSONSerialization). Since I don't know the names of player1 and player 2 constantly I can't use objectForKey (which in testing, ex knowing player1 is the name of a player etc, works). So I use objectAtIndex which causes a crash, "-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance".
**JSON:**

```
{
  "id": "idnumb",
  "numentrants": 2,
  "entrants": {
    "player1": {
    "displayname": "player1",
    "otherdata": 1234,
    },
    "player2": {
      "displayname": "player2",
      "otherdata": 5678,
    }
  }
}
```

**Obj C:**

```
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSDictionary *eventArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

for(int i = 0; i < [[eventArray objectForKey:@"entrants"] count]; i++)
{
   NSArray *entrantsArray = [[eventArray objectForKey:@"entrants"] objectAtIndex:i];
   NSLog(@"%@", entrantsArray);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you Google your question title, the *very first* reference is a duplicate of yours.  (Or, rather, yours is a duplicate of that one.)

Comment: BTW, you should go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn, and knowing it will save you from asking duplicate questions like this.

Comment: The info on the marked duplicate didn't solve the issue. However, nzeltzer's allValues solution did.

Comment: The dupe explained your problem.  Using allValues to get around the problem is a bit of a kluge, but then the original JSON is badly kluged to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entrants is a dictionary, not an array. :)

You can use the NSObject isKindOfClass method to check whether elements of the parsed JSON are dictionaries or arrays, and then handle them appropriately.

If you want to access a dictionary's values by index, you can retrieve an array of values by calling NSDictionary's allValues method.

Comment: Changing it to a dictionary causes the same issue, `NSDictionary *entrantsArray = [[eventArray objectForKey:@"entrants"] objectAtIndex:i];`

Comment: id events = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonParsingError]; // Then check the type with isKindOfClass. If it's a dictionary, you can access by key. If it's an array, you can access by index. If for some reason you want to access a dictionary's values by index, use the allValues method to get an array of the dictionary's values.

Comment: `NSDictionary *entrantsArray = [[[specificRaceArray objectForKey:@"entrants"] allValues] objectAtIndex:i];` appears to work, thanks for the allValues tip!

Answer (score 1):

None of the objects in your JSON data are arrays, there are only dictionaries. You need to enumerate over it like a dictionary, not an array, for example:

```
NSDictionary *entrants = [eventArray objectForKey:@"entrants"];
for(NSString *playerName in entrants)
{
   NSLog(@"%@", playerName);

   NSDictionary *playerData = [entrants objectForKey:playerName];
   for (NSString *dataName in playerData)
   {
      NSLog(@"%@: %@", dataName, [playerData objectForKey:dataName]);
   }
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right: no arrays in sight!